# How can I map a nullable tinyint column to a bool where null becomes false in EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I maintain a suite of applications for a SqlServer database that has no simple creation process and various instances in production have slight differences (with regards nullability of columns and varchar sizes).  I am moving the data layer of these applications from EF 6 to EF Core 2.1 to increase platform support and to finally have a straightforward way to create new databases with a consistent layout.

I might take this opportunity to clean up my POCOs somewhat.  One pattern I wish to do away with is that original SqlServer database often uses `tinyint null` instead of `bit` columns with a default constraint on them.  These are mapped to `byte?` rather than `bool` in my C# code which I think needlessly complicates their usage.  Going forward, I'd like new databases to use bit fields instead, and in many cases it is appropriate for them to be not null and defaulted to 0.  I have this working, but I figured that with all the flexibility of EF Core, I should be able to subclass my DbContext and provide different mappings in order to enable the same code to run against the original "legacy" databases there these are still nullable tinyints instead.

**Attempt 1**
I was hoping to use a `ValueConverter<bool, byte?>` in my LegacyDbContext subclass to accomplish this (passing it into `PropertyBuilder<bool>.HasConversion`) until I learnt that these cannot be used to convert nulls under the limitations section of the [EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions), so I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` stating:
`An exception occurred while reading a database value for property '<tableName>.<columnName>'. The expected type was 'System.Boolean' but the actual value was null.`

**Attempt 2**
Registering a custom `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.IEntityMaterializerSource` implementation to take care of this conversion for me but I couldn't get that working either, I think it is invoked too late for me to do the type conversion...

Surely it is possible to replace nulls with 0 prior to the type conversion from byte to bool, or some other mechanism to accomplish my new POCOs using bools to be mapped back to the nullable tinyints of older databases?